# No data on Neo4j Web UI

Tags: java, neo4j

I'm new to Neo4j, currently I'm trying to insert some graphs on it, following  https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/2.0.0/community/embedded-examples/src/main/java/org/neo4j/examples/EmbeddedNeo4jWithNewIndexing.java  I have built a test example as a stand alone java application.

Nodes and relations are getting inserted, I can tell this because every time I run my code one more node with id '555' is retrieved on the query. However I can't find any node or relation on the web UI. Both my example and the web UI should be reading the same data, as far as I know this is done with the line:

```
`private static final String DB_PATH = "http://localhost:7474/db/data";`
```

Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong?, Thanks a lot

Just in case you need it, This is my full code

```
public class EmbeddedNeo4jWithNewIndexing {

private static final String DB_PATH = "http://localhost:7474/db/data";

public static void main(final String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Starting database ...");
    GraphDatabaseService graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(DB_PATH);
    {
        try (Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx()) {
            Label label = DynamicLabel.label("User");

            for (int id = 0; id < 1000; id++) {
                Node userNode = graphDb.createNode(label);
                userNode.setProperty("username", "user" + id + "@neo4j.org");
            }
            System.out.println("Users created");
            tx.success();
        }
    }

    {
        Label label = DynamicLabel.label("User");
        int idToFind = 555;
        String nameToFind = "user" + idToFind + "@neo4j.org";
        try (Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx()) {
            try (ResourceIterator<Node> users
                    = graphDb.findNodesByLabelAndProperty(label, "username", nameToFind).iterator()) {
                ArrayList<Node> userNodes = new ArrayList<>();
                while (users.hasNext()) {
                    userNodes.add(users.next());
                }

                for (Node node : userNodes) {
                    System.out.println("The username of user " + idToFind + " is " + node.getProperty("username"));
                }
                tx.success();
            }
        }
    }


    System.out.println("Shutting down database ...");
    graphDb.shutdown();
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is your DB_PATH declaration. This isn't intended to be a URL, it is intended to be a path to a folder accessible to your local machine. I'm a little surprised that your code succeeds, but you are definitely not connecting to the same database as when you are working via the Web UI. Find the location of the graph.db folder (that's the default name for the graph database root folder) and set DB_PATH to the path for that folder. I expect that this will solve your problem.